# Flutter: check "Ensure you are using Package x.y.z+" requirement

Tags: dart, flutter, package-managers

Is there a straightforward way to check a particular installed package? I tried help for `pub` and `flutter`, then Google; still nothing.

I can look up `pubspec.yaml`, of course, but it is a requirement, not the actual package installed. There must be a way.

Comment: Is it really `$ flutter pub pub deps | grep Package`? Is the `grep` indispensable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dart the command to view all dependencies is:

```
pub deps
```

In flutter:

```
flutter pub pub deps
```

In order to filter a dependency in particular you can use grep, by example:

```
flutter pub pub deps | grep flutter_secure_storage
```