# Can I see if another dart/flutter package is installed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am planning to make a package that has *x* functionality enabled. However, if package *p* is installed, how can I make my package enable *y* functionality?

I cannot have package *p* give any info to my package, so having them cross-communicate in some way wouldn't work.

---

Therefore, in Dart (with or without Flutter), can I programatically check to see if another Dart/Flutter package has been installed in the project (added to pubspec.yaml and available)?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114144/flutter-check-ensure-you-are-using-package-x-y-z-requirement) is what you are looking for.

Comment: No sorry, that is looking if a package is installed through the command line. I need to do this check programatically.

Comment: You could add _p_ as a dependency in your package. The tree shaken code should be the same, and not be included if it isn't used by users of your package.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could consider this, but I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this through extension methods and a seperate export/import file for 'plugins'/modules/extensions only.
Unfortunately, this won't allow for new non-methods, such as variables, but getters may be used instead.

To implement a similar system:

1. Add a mostly empty object to the primary library
   It should include a reference variable/getter to the 'root' object of the primary library, or whatever object the plugin requires.
   *See [this](https://github.com/JaffaKetchup/flutter_map_tile_caching/blob/3d723ed052f0e27de50e2f3db351ad95e43c5516/lib/src/store/export.dart) for an example implementation*
2. Create an extension method for the object above to the secondary library
   *See [this](https://github.com/JaffaKetchup/fmtc_plus_sharing/blob/8fda5fab96405cbf08cc1f0d2e3e554eb2b6562f/lib/src/export.dart) for an example implementation*
3. In the primary library, create a new export/import file that the secondary library can use

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if a package is globally installed by checking if a directory exists: (pub cache)/global_packages/package_name.

The DCli api has the following method:

```dart
DartSdk().isPackageGloballyActivated(String package)
```

So to check if dcli is globally active:

```dart
DartSdk().isPackageGloballyActivated('dcli');
```